# How do you identify models that contain related records in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm sure my wording isn't great which explains why I'm failing at searching. I'm trying to work out how to identify records that are related to two others. Example will make it clearer.

Model **Contest** has a has_many relation to **Results**. The results have a Team number(but lets use letters for Clarity)

So in this example I'm trying to find all the Contests that Team A and Team D have both attended.

I want to get back a enumerator of all the Contests that fit this condition so I can then compare the two teams to each other.

I apologize for this not being the best write up, I'm struggling for the terms to define what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your help, time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
class Contest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :results
  has_many :teams, through: :results
end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
  belongs_to :contest
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :result
  delegate :contest, to: :result
end
```

This will set up your associations, and let you access `Contest` from `Team`. The `delegate` method says "if I call `team.contest`, do `team.result.contest` instead".

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

And if you're wanting to gather the contests:

`Contest.joins(results: :teams).where(teams: { id: team_a.id })`
`Contest.joins(results: :teams).where(teams: { id: team_b.id })`

Comment: Thank-you! I should of included the included the Models I had set up but now glad I didn't! I wasn't aware of the delegate on a model, always used the 'through:" option. The code on the bottom is much appreciated for answering the question as well,Thank-you, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you would need to join the same table twice, once with team A results and once with team B results. You need to reference them as separate tables. You can use Arel and assign unique names to the two instance of the table.

```
contests_between = Arel::Table.new(:contests, as: 'contests_between')
team_a_results = Arel::Table.new(:results, as: team_a_results)
team_b_results = Arel::Table.new(:results, as: team_b_results)

relation = contests_between.project(Arel.sql('*')).
join(team_a_results).on(contests_between[:id].eq(team_a_results[:contest_id])).
join(team_b_results).on(contests_between[:id].eq(team_b_results[:contest_id]))

And then you can do...

relation = relation.where(team_a_results[:team_id].eq(1)).where(team_b_results[:team_id].eq(2))

@contests = relation.to_sql

# above assumes team_a is id 1 and team_b is id 2... if the teams are already loaded you could substitute team_a.id and team_b.id
```